# Fontspec error in xelatex

Tags: errors, fontspec

I am using `xelatex` for my documents, in greek language, and today I decided to do an update of some Miktex packages. After the update I get the following error in many documents:

`Undefined control sequence. \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }`

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside,nofonts]{article}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0,BoldFont={Times New Roman Bold}]{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
Math
\end{document}
```

Is there anything wrong with the new `fontspec` package?

Comment: (I used both xelatex and lualatex without error with an up to date texlive) also can you show the error from the log in a code section, the form you show isn't the format tex uses so it's impossible to see which command is undefined as the error is shown above.

Comment: Works ok for me on miktex. Check the log-file for old packages that need to be updated too.

Comment: it is not possible to tell from the question as posted but if the undefined command is `\eminnershape` then your latex format must be older than 2015/01/09

Comment: The problem was the fontspec package itself. I reupdated the package to the latest cersion (6-2017) and the problem was solved.

Comment: I had the same problem, all with latex3 (supposedly) and stuff. This seems to have been solved in a more recent update of fontspec.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem (on Windows) by uninstalling and installing again the fontspec package via MiKTeX Package Manager (Admin).