# Trouble with Old Standard TT font

Tags: fonts, xetex, miktex

I'm trying to use Old Standard TT font on my MikTeX 2.9 but I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried several things some have posted in the past such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398353/144601) but no luck. Here's what I got:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard TT}

 \title{Sample font document}
 \author{}
 \date{12/29/17}

\begin{document}

 \maketitle

 This works on Overleaf but not on my MikTex 2.9. What is wrong?

\end{document}
```

And this is what I get as an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \c__fontspec_shape_n_n_tl used!
l.3806 \emfontdeclare{ \emshape, \eminnershape }

?
```

It works on Overleaf but not on my MikTeX. Any suggestions? Also, is there another font very similar to Old Standard that is compatible with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: May be `\setmainfont{Old Standard}`

Comment: Didn't work. Interestingly, that doesn't work either on Overleaf.

Comment: That error indicates that  your system is not uptodate.  Run the update manager  as user  and ad admin.

Answer (score 4):

There's a version of `Old Standard` in .otf format, and there's a version in `.ttf` format. The latter is called `Old Standard TT`, whereas the former is called "just" `Old Standard`. Both versions provide three files, each with a distinct font shape and weight: upright, bold, and italic (but no bold-italic).

Assuming you installed the font files in a way that updated the list of system fonts, the following code should work:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OldStandard}%
       [Extension = .ttf, % or: .otf
        Path=/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/, % or whatever is appropriate for a Windows system
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        BoldFont    = *-Bold,
        ItalicFont  = *-Italic]
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{OldStandard}%
       [Extension = .ttf, % or: ".otf"
        Path=/Users/mico/Library/Fonts/, % set this as appropriate
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        BoldFont    = *-Bold,
        ItalicFont  = *-Italic]

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog on MacTeX2017.
\end{document}
```